# How to enforce author/commiter authentication in git?

Tags: git, tfvc

We are currently using git for version control in our project. The development environment is an intranet (windows servers with an AD) with no internet access. Is there a way to configure git to use the developers' domain logins for author and committer? We want to prevent developers from being able to supply this information themselves. I found this when googling the issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc

For auditability it states for git:
"You can identify which user pushed a commit. (Anyone can claim any identity as the author or committer.) You can identify when changes were made what was changed using history, compare, and annotate."

And for TFVC:
"Because your team checks in all their work into a centralized system, you can identify which user checked in a changeset and use compare to see what they changed. Looking at a file, you can annotate it to identify who changed a block of code, and when they did it."

Based purely on those texts it would seem that we should move to TFVC.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

### Git

Due to the distributed nature in Git it would still be possible for one user to make changes with user ABC, push them directly to a colleague who's username is CBA and then that colleague then pushes the changes to the central server.

The central server has no way to know whether all of these commits were written by user ABC or CBA to begin with, let alone whether the user pushing the data is the user who wrote the code

This is why the server maintains the Pusher of the code.

Git's solution for this is to sign your commits using GPG prior to distributing them. Only the users who have the private key can sign a commit on their own behalf. They can sign changes that came in from other people as well, basically stating that they have reviewed the code. You'd sign off a release or after an audit has been performed to ensure consistency up to that point. Any changes to the history beyond that point would invalidate the signature. I wouldn't recommend signing every commit because the signature will break when rebasing, could get lost when squash-merging.

The inability to enforce the author is an inherent feature of the distributed nature of Git.

It would be relatively easy to include a Windows Logon script that patches the central git configuration file to set the username to the one you want though, probably even easier than a pre-commit-hook. Just call:

```
$ git config --global user.name "User's Name"
$ git config --global user.email "name@domain"
```

### TFVC

In TFVC there are also models to move code from one dev to another using Shelvesets. Shelvesets can be created by one dev, unshelved by another and then checked-into the central repository. This would also register the user who did the check-in as the author. Not the author of the code.

The reason is that TFVC doesn't distinguish between the author and the pusher. It assumes both are always the same. That doesn't hold true for Git in many cases.

TFVC checkins are also not as mutable as git commits, the commit message can be easily changed through after the fact using the API or the Visual Studio UI though. As can Checkin notes.

### Just think of it

Anyone could put a change on a USB key, move to another computer and put the change in another user's workspace. You could even email it, or with the right permission in TFS act on behalf of someone else.

### Possible options

As mentioned before, you can:

- use a pre-commit hook in git to detect misconfiguration of the name/email in the git settings.
- automatically set the correct default values through policy
- use a server-side service hook to automatically flag pull requests that contain mismatches (though I would not block them, sharing code between authors outside of the central repo is a very powerful collaboration option).
- use a custom build step to flag suspect changes during Build and either partially succeed or plain fail the build.
- I suspect you could extend the git client (git is very configurable in this way) to enforce the correct names when performing a commit, but that would require you to distribute a custom git configuration.

Git has no built-in measures to ensure the configured name matches the actual user. But it's impact can be limited. As long as people review other people's changes before pushing, the Pusher field will reflect who decided to actually make these changes part of the main repository, regardless of the person who wrote the code. In many cases that's a far more important decision.

My recommendation would be not to use TFVC if you're making a choice right now.

Comment: Don't forget that VSTS and TFS log the identity of the person who has pushed every commit, which is authenticated and cannot be forged in this manner.

Comment: Right. But they could be pushing commits with the name of a different person.

Comment: Ok. If we put the USB key issue aside, I undestand it that it is the authenticated user in VSTS and TFS that is logged as the author when doing a commit? Even if working with Shelvesets that holds true?

Comment: @jessehouwing: According to my understanding there is no way to enforce the usage of PGP-keys in git. Is that correct? Or can you configure git to only allow for PGP signed commits?

Comment: You don't really want only signed commits. You'd sign a release or a piece of audited code to ensure that that piece doesn't change anymore. You want freedom during development, merge, rebase and such. Them optionally sign off a release.

Comment: The author of a change that came in through a shelfset in reality is not the person performing the checkin, only TFS doesn't even register this information.

Comment: @jessehouwing: In this particular case I actually want only signed commits. It would in our project not have a significant impact on the freedom.

Answer (score 1):

1. Tell the members how to config `user.name` and `user.email` with proper values.
2. Make a white list which contains the valid names and emails. Install a `pre-receive` hook in the remote repository on the server. Check every commit if its names and emails of the author and the committer are in the white list. If a commit contains any invalid name or email, decline the push and return instructions how to fix. Depending on your hosting service, the hook may have a different name.

Comment: That still allows members to use eachothers' user.name and user.email values, right?

Comment: @Pelle Yes. It's hard to control what users can or can't do in their local repositories as Git is distributed. You can install a hook in their machines to check if their user.name and user.email are valid. But they can always find a way to bypass it.

Comment: Ok. In our case we have tough requirements for auditability and non repudiation for check ins to the central repo. It sounds that git is not a very good choice for us then?

Comment: @Pelle It depends. Git itself is not good at access control. But a hosting service like Gitlab can fill the gaps. You could learn more about pros and cons of available version control systems and find out which is best for your project.